# javascript: how to turn two 1D arrays into a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to prepare data for using in a google chart. my input is:

```
myHeader = ["header 1", "header 2"];
myCol1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myCol2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
```

What I need is this:

```
myData = [["header1", "header2"],[1,100],[2, 200], [3, 300],[4, 400], [5, 500]];
```

how can I convert it? I tried with `push` but had no lock to push `[1,100]` into an array containing `["header1", "header2"]`

This is what I tried before:

```
var myDATA = [new Array('header1', 'header2'), two1dto2d(myDate, myTemp)];

function two1dto2d(a,b) {
    var c = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        A = new Array(a[i],b[i]);
        console.log(A);
        c.push(A);
    }
    return c
};
```

but the result is not what I expected:

[image]
any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get with that is a three dimensional array, as you are putting the column pairs into an array, which you in turn put in the final array.

You need to push the column pairs into the outmost array. For example like this:

```
var myDATA = [new Array('header1', 'header2')];
two1dto2d(myDATA, myDate, myTemp);

function two1dto2d(c, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c.push([a[i], b[i]]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/pXLLz/

```
myHeader = ["header 1", "header 2"];
myCol1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myCol2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];

mydata = [myHeader];

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    mydata.push([myCol1[i],myCol2[i]]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(mydata));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var output=[myHeader];
for(i=0;i<myCol1.length;i++){
   output.push( [myCol1[i], myCol2[i] ]);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hyPuJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Other than the header, you're looking to do something commonly called `zip` as seen in underscore http://underscorejs.org/#zip

```
myHeader = ["header 1", "header 2"];
myCol1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myCol2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];

// basic zip implementation
var zip = function (arr1, arr2) {
    var len = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
    var arr = new Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        arr[i] = [arr1[i], arr2[i]];
    }
    return arr; 
};
data = [myHeader].concat(zip(myCol1, myCol2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I came up with since I didn't notice the `[  ]` in all the other answers before:

```
var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var bar = [1,2,3,4];
var ar2 = [];

for(var i in arr) {
    var ar3 = []
    ar3.push(foo[i], bar[i]);
    ar2.push(ar3);
}
console.log(ar2);
```

Answer (score 0):

General version of the function:

```
Array.prototype.mergeWith = function(...args) {
    // PREPARATION
    let L = this.length, // memorize the length of `this` array
        n = 0, array, // iterators
        res = []; // the result will be here

    // CALCULATION
    for (; n < L; n++) // iterate over the length of `this`
        for (array of args) // iterate over `args`
            if (array instanceof Array && array.length === L) // if `array` is really an array and it is as lengthy as `this`, …
                res.push([this[n], array[n]]); // … push every n-th object of `array` to n-th array of `res`
            else return; // check whether all the operands are arrays of the same length
    return res; // eventually return result
}
```

Same thing minified:

```
Array.prototype.mergeWith = function(...A) {
    let L = this.length, r = [], n = 0, a;
    for (; n < L; n++) for (a of A) if (a instanceof Array && a.length === L) r.push([this[n], a[n]]); else return;
    return r;
}
```

---

Use:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var A = arr1.mergeWith(arr2);
// [ [1, "a"],
//   [2, "b"],
//   [3, "c"],
//   [4, "d"] ]

var arr3 = [[31, 32], [33, 34], [35, 36], [37, 38]];

var B = arr1.mergeWith(arr2, arr3);
// [ [1, "a", [ 31, 32 ]],
//   [2, "b", [ 33, 34 ]],
//   [3, "c", [ 35, 36 ]],
//   [4, "d", [ 37, 38 ]] ]
```

---

Use in your particular case:

```
myData = myCol1.mergeWith(myCol2);
myData.unshift(myHeader);
// [ ["header1", "header2"],
//   [1, 100],
//   [2, 200],
//   [3, 300],
//   [4, 400],
//   [5, 500]               ];
```